# Build git on embedded system

Tags: git

I want to build git on our embedded system and I got git's source code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list).

I run `./configure` tool with following arguments:

```
./configure --build=arm-eabi --host=`uname -p`-`uname -s`-`uname -o`
```

Configure tool runs, and returns an error says:

```
checking whether system succeeds to read fopen'ed directory...configure: error: in`/home/git-1.8.0.2`.
```

I set necessary environment variables like `CC` and `CXX` to our tool chain already, so `./configure` complains nothing about compilers.
But I have no idea about that error message. It looks like some permission problem, but I have full permission of `/home/git-1.8.0.2` for sure.
Any idea ?

Comment: Which distro do you use?

Comment: Apart curiosity and challenge, what is the need for a version control system on an embedded system?

Comment: Post the complete `config.log`.

Comment: [config.log](http://pastebin.com/DrHvPSv9)

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the `configure` script, you will find that it tries to perform a check that requires executing a test program. But because you are cross compiling, `configure` knows that it can't get reliable results that way so it does not even try but bails out.

`configure` can handle cached values from previous runs and does that with the help of environment variables. You can use that same mechanism to tell `configure` what to assume for the tests it can't perform (for the currently failing test, that would be `ac_cv_fread_reads_directories=no`).

---

As a side note, you have the `--build` and `--host` parameters the wrong way around. `--build` should indicate the machine on which the build is being performed, while `--host` should indicate the machine on which the final software will run.

The name provided for `--host` is also assumed to be the prefix of the cross-compilation toolchain, so there is no need to explicitly set `CC` and `CXX`

Comment: I swap `--build` and `--host` parameters and it is ok.

But I must set `CC` and `CXX` to my compiler of toolchain or `./configure` will get wrong compiler.

What should I do to assign `no` to `ac_cv_fread_reads_directories`? Environment variable? Or edit `./configure` ?

Comment: Set it as an environment variable, and `./configure` should pick it up automatically.

Comment: If your C cross-compiler is called `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, then it should be picked up automatically with the option`--host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi` without setting `CC`